# Time-inputfield for quick entering

Tags: java, time, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield, documentfilter

I want a quick-to-use way for entering times down to centiseconds. Entering digits should push them in from the right and automatically add leading zeros, "." and ":" as needed, so for example:

"" => "0.03" => "0.31" => "3.14" => "31.41" => "3:14.15"

Also, entering "f" should result in "DNF" ("did not finish"):
"3:14.15" => "DNF" => "0.04"

My code below "works", except it always puts the cursor at the end (because I full-replace), which is not nice when someone tries to edit in the middle. Is there an easy way to keep the cursor where it should be? And more importantly, is my whole approach proper at all or I should really do this differently? I've tried many ways before (JFormattedTextField and Formatters, DocumentFilter, DocumentListener, etc), some because they were suggested here for similar things, but couldn't get them to work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class TimeField extends JTextField {

  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add( new TimeField() );
    frame.add( new TimeField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }

  TimeField () {
    super( 10 );
    setHorizontalAlignment( RIGHT );
    setFont( new Font( "MONOSPACED", Font.BOLD, 32 ));
    ((AbstractDocument) getDocument()).setDocumentFilter( new DocumentFilter() {
      public void insertString ( DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr ) throws BadLocationException {
        replace( fb, offset, 0, string, attr );
      }
      public void remove ( DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length ) throws BadLocationException {
        replace( fb, offset, length, "", null );
      }
      public void replace ( DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs ) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.replace( offset,length, text, attrs );
        if ( text.contains("f") ) {
          fb.replace( 0, getText().length(), "DNF", null );
          return;
        }
        text = getText();                                 // get current text
        text = text.replaceAll( "\\D", "" );              // remove non-digits
        text = text.replaceAll( "^0+", "" );              // remove leading zeros
        while ( text.length() < 3 ) text = "0" + text;    // make at least three digits
        text = text.replaceAll( "(.)(..)$", "$1.$2" );    // add point if necessary
        text = text.replaceAll( "(.)(..\\.)", "$1:$2" );  // add colon if necessary
        fb.replace( 0, getText().length(), text, null );  // replace original with formatted
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Edit:
I tried JFormattedTextField before, here's my best attempt. I can enter digits and when the focus leaves the field, valueToString gets called and adds point+colon which is then displayed. But I'd like this to be done *during* editing, not after. I must be missing something, as MaskFormatter can apparently do that.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class TimeField extends JFormattedTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Create Event Disptach Thread for  swing UI and its components to run on 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(new TimeFormatter());
                ftf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
                ftf.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 32));
                ftf.setColumns(10);
                frame.getContentPane().add(ftf);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("foo"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class TimeFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {
        public Object stringToValue(String text) {
            System.out.println("stringToValue(" + text + ")");
            return text == null ? "" : text.replaceAll("\\D", "");
        }
        public String valueToString(Object value) {
            System.out.println("valueToString(" + value + ")");
            return value == null ? null : format((String)value);
        }
        private String format(String text) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\D", "");              // remove non-digits
            text = text.replaceAll("^0+", "");              // remove leading zeros
            while (text.length() < 3) text = "0" + text;    // make at least three digits
            text = text.replaceAll("(.)(..)$", "$1.$2");    // add point
            text = text.replaceAll("(.)(..\\.)", "$1:$2");  // add colon if necessary
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I've seen that before (even recognized your name :-) and wasn't happy with any of those. We have to enter hundreds or thousands of times a day, most under a minute, so we're after a way to just enter the needed digits. MaskFormatter is interesting, but doesn't seem to work right-aligning (and we don't want to have to always manually move to the start position) and I don't see how to support the "DNF".

Comment: It should be like that if you entered 0:23 and then delete the '2'. It's confusing to have the cursor jump to the end, and actually bad if you want to continue where you were (inserting or deleting more there). And can you tell about my main question, whether this approach is the right one at all or I should really be using for example JFormattedTextField with some Formatter instead? I know formatters and filters have different purposes and yet other ways might have further different purposes, but I don't fully understand them.

Comment: I don't think it violates the JFormattedTextField purpose. Think of the value not as a "time" but as a "result", which is either a time or DNF (or DNS=DidNotStart, omitted here for simplicity). In the end, internally they'll even all be handled as a number, with DNF/DNS negative. I said "time" in the question title because people wouldn't know what I mean with "result" and because my main problem is with the times. Thanks for the advice about frames.